# R Count unique values without specific symbol

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, count, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe 'df' that has categorical and POSIXct columns. The data look like:

| Category | DateTime |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| A | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| A 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| A 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| A 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 |
| A | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |
| A 1 | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |
| B | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |
| B | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |
| B | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |
| B 1 | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 |

I would like to create a new dataframe 'df2' that counts each unique value in column 'Category' that doesn't end with " 1" by column 'DateTime', so that the results look like:

| Category | DateTime | CatCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 | 2 |
| B | 2022-08-29 00:00:00 | 3 |
| A | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 | 1 |
| B | 2022-08-29 02:00:00 | 3 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could `filter` output the rows having 1, then do a `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   filter(str_detect(Category, "\\s+1", negate = TRUE)) %>%
   count(Category, DateTime, name = "CatCount")
```

-output

```
 Category            DateTime CatCount
1        A 2022-08-29 00:00:00        2
2        A 2022-08-29 02:00:00        1
3        B 2022-08-29 00:00:00        3
4        B 2022-08-29 02:00:00        3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A 1", "A 1", "A 1", "B", 
"B", "B", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1", "A", "A 1", "B", 
"B", "B", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1"), DateTime = c("2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another base R solution with `transform` + `aggregate`:

```r
transform(df1[!grepl("1$", df1$Category),], count = 1) |>
  aggregate(count ~ Category + DateTime, data = _, length)

  Category            DateTime count
1        A 2022-08-29 00:00:00     2
2        B 2022-08-29 00:00:00     3
3        A 2022-08-29 02:00:00     1
4        B 2022-08-29 02:00:00     3
```

Comment: Also `aggregate(count ~ ., data = _, length)` will work instead of `aggregate(count ~ Category + DateTime, data = _, length)`

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  filter(!endsWith(Category, "1")) %>%
  count(Category, DateTime)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or a `base` solution using `table`:

```r
df[nchar(df$Category) == 1,] |>
  table() |>
  as.data.frame(responseName = "CatCount")
```

We could of course subset in various ways `df[!endsWith(df$Category, "1"),]` (as @ Gregor Thomas) or `df[!grepl("\\s+1", df$Category),]` (as @ akrun).

**Output:**

```r
  Category            DateTime CatCount
1        A 2022-08-29 00:00:00        2
2        B 2022-08-29 00:00:00        3
3        A 2022-08-29 02:00:00        1
4        B 2022-08-29 02:00:00        3
```

**Data:**

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_delim("Category,DateTime
A,2022-08-29 00:00:00
A,2022-08-29 00:00:00
A 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
A 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
A 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 00:00:00
A,2022-08-29 02:00:00
A 1,2022-08-29 02:00:00
B,2022-08-29 02:00:00
B,2022-08-29 02:00:00
B,2022-08-29 02:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 02:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 02:00:00
B 1,2022-08-29 02:00:00", delim = ",")
```

**Update:** Data added.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` option, where we can use `grepl` (or could also use `stringr`) to ignore any rows that contain a number in `Category`, then count using `.N`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[!grepl("\\d", Category), .N, .(Category, DateTime)]
```

**Output**

```
   Category            DateTime N
1:        A 2022-08-29 00:00:00 2
2:        B 2022-08-29 00:00:00 3
3:        A 2022-08-29 02:00:00 1
4:        B 2022-08-29 02:00:00 3
```

**Data**

```
dt <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A 1", "A 1", "A 1", "B", 
"B", "B", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1", "A", "A 1", "B", 
"B", "B", "B 1", "B 1", "B 1"), DateTime = c("2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", "2022-08-29 00:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00", 
"2022-08-29 02:00:00", "2022-08-29 02:00:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We may conveniently use the `subset` argument of `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(cbind(CatCount=rep(1, length(Category))) ~ Category + DateTime, df1, length, 
          subset=!grepl('1', Category))
#   Category            DateTime CatCount
# 1        A 2022-08-29 00:00:00        2
# 2        B 2022-08-29 00:00:00        3
# 3        A 2022-08-29 02:00:00        1
# 4        B 2022-08-29 02:00:00        3
```

Data borrowed from *@akrun*.